# Powershell remove-item won't delete files

Tags: powershell, file-handling

I have a PowerShell 5.1 script that should delete some files. However, when I try to delete them, neither `del` nor `remove-item` appear to be working. I have alredy set the execution policy to Unrestricted, and launched the ISE in admin mode. Even moving the file with `Move-Item` didn't work.

My code:

```
$startROMFolderPath = "C:\Users\VincentGuttmann\Desktop\retropie-mount\roms" #Pleae enter the path to your current ROM folder here, ending in the roms folder. Note that this script will only work if the ROMs are inside the RetroPie folder.
$deleteROMFolder = $startROMFolderPath + "\delete"
Write-Host @"
Hello!
Welcome to my ROM Sorting program!
There are three main ROM types: 
The ROMs that are "known good", which are marked with this tag: [!],
the bad dumps, so "known bad", which are marked [b].
Then there are the ROMs where we don't know.

The ROMs that are known good will be left in the folder.
The bad dumps will be deleted right away, as well as the ROMs which are neither German nor English
If you haven't put in the paths to your current ROM folder, 
please exit the program now by pressing enter and then "n" without quotation marks.
"@

$inputted = Read-Host -Prompt 'Have you changed the paths accordingly? Yes: (y), No: anything else than (y)'

$i = 0

if($inputted -eq "y")
{
  $foldersOld = @()

  Get-ChildItem $startROMFolderPath -Attributes Directory |
  foreach {
    $foldersOld += $_
  }

  foreach ($name in $foldersOld) {
  $currentROMFolderPath = $StartROMFolderPath + "\" + $name
  $ROMList = @()

  Get-ChildItem $currentROMFolderPath -File |
  foreach {
    $currentROMPath = $currentROMFolderPath + "\" + $_
    $containsBad = $_ -match "\[b.\]"
    $containsGood = $_ -match "\[!\]"
    $containsLang = $_ -match ".*(\([UE]+\))|(\(U\).*\(E.*\))|(\(E.*\).*\(U\))|(\(E.*\))|(\([UKNG4A]+\))|(\(Unl\))"

    if($containsBad)
    {
      write-host "====================================="
      Write-Host $_
      Write-Host "contains bad"
      write-host "====================================="
      Remove-Item -Path $currentROMPath -Force
    }
    #Put "!$containsGood -and !$containsLang" into the next bracket if you want to delete all ROMS that are neither good nor in the correct Language.
    #For just keeping ROMs in the corect language, plase use "!$containsLang"
    elseif(!$containsGood -and !$containsLang)
    {
      write-host "====================================="
      Write-Host $_
      Write-Host "Contains no good and no lang"  
      write-host $currentROMPath
      write-host "====================================="
      Remove-Item -Path $currentROMPath -Force
    }
    }
  }
}

else
{
  exit
}

exit
```

Comment: Is it that your `*-Item` commands "didn't work" or they (and their surrounding `if` blocks) are not even being executed?  What output does your script produce and for what input files?  By the way, the first few lines of your `if($inputted -eq "y")` block can be simplified to `$foldersOld = @(Get-ChildItem $startROMFolderPath -Attributes Directory)`.

Comment: All was executed properly, and the print statement worked also flawlessly. just the deleting doesn't work

Comment: What outputs when you add the `-Verbose` flag to `Remove-Item`?

Comment: I got it figured out, that's embarrassing. I tried to hunt down that mistake for hours, and then I went to StackOverflow, and literally five minutes later I realize I could use `-LiteralPath`, and it works flawlessly...